# MySql query to insert row with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to add a new row for all post_ids that equal specific condition. So there is a table with `post_id`, `meta_key` and `meta_value`

| id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | page-type | city |
| 2 | 100 | banner | "banner" |
| 3 | 101 | page-type | city |
| 4 | 102 | page-type | city |
| 5 | 102 | banner | "new banner |
| 6 | 111 | page-type | non-city |
| 7 | 111 | banner | "non-citybanner" |

I need to add for post_id that has `meta_key = "page-type"` and `meta_value = "city"` while `meta_key = "banner"` does not exist. In this example I should have a new row

| id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 101 | banner | "my new banner" |

Of course the table contains about 200K such rows :)
Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any other tables?  For example, you should ideally have a dimensional table for your posts *(one row per post, where post_id is the primary key)*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO
  post (
    post_id,
    meta_key,
    meta_value
  )
SELECT
  post_id,
  'banner',
  '"my new banner"'
FROM
  your_meta_table
GROUP BY
  post_id
HAVING
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'banner' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
  AND
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'page-type' AND meta_value = 'city' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

Or, preferably...

```
INSERT INTO
  post (
    post_id,
    meta_key,
    meta_value
  )
SELECT
  post_id,
  'banner',
  '"my new banner"'
FROM
  your_posts_table
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM your_meta_table
     WHERE post_id = your_posts_table.post_id
       AND meta_key = 'banner'
  )
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM your_meta_table
     WHERE post_id = your_posts_table.post_id
       AND meta_key = 'page-type'
       AND meta_value = 'city'
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8.3 you can:

- select the all "*post_id*" values that satisfy `meta_key = 'page_type'` and `meta_value = 'city'`,
- subtract all ids that have banners with the [`EXCEPT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/except.html) operation.
- apply the insertion

```
INSERT INTO tab(post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT post_id, 
       'banner' AS meta_key, 
       'new_banner' AS meta_value
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM tab WHERE meta_key = 'page-type' AND meta_value = 'city'
      EXCEPT
      SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM tab WHERE meta_key = 'banner') missing_ids;
```

Answer (score -1):

You should do a Select into a temp-table to achieve this.

First, we select all rows with your condition:

```
SELECT (post_id) FROM [table] where meta_key = 'page-type' and meta_value='city' and 
post_id not in (SELECT post_id FROM [table] WHERE meta_key='page-type' and meta_value='banner')
```

this selection gives you a list of post_ids where no banner-entry exists

Now you can use the found post_ids to insert into your table the data you need:

```
INSERT INTO [table] (id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value) 

SELECT id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM (
   SELECT null AS 'id', post_id, 'page-type', 'banner' 
         FROM [table] 
               WHERE meta_key = 'page-type' 
                     AND meta_value='city' 
                     AND post_id not in (
                          SELECT post_id FROM [table] 
                                 WHERE meta_key='page-type' AND meta_value='banner'
                          )
 ) as TEMP
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do as follows :

take also the case where if banner exist create page-type

```
INSERT into _metas (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
select post_id, if(meta_key = 'page-type', 'banner', 'page-type'), if(meta_key = 'page-type', 'my banner', 'my city')
    from your_meta_table
    group by post_id
    having count(*) = 1;
```